# Odoo retrieve field from other module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

Odoo 10

I am trying to copy a field from the products to the Sales order. The field in the products is called default_code. I've tried copying code from the Sales order module as its already getting unit price and tax etc. but cannot get it working.

```
from odoo import api, models, fields

class myfieldsinsaleorder(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    squaremtr = fields.Float("SQ Meter Required")
    boxes = fields.Float("Suggested Boxes")
    squarebox = fields.Char("Meters Per Box")

    @api.onchange('product_id', 'default_code', 'price_unit', 'product_uom', 'product_uom_qty', 'tax_id')
    def _onchange_discount(self):
        self.discount = 0.0
        self.squarebox = 'default_code'
```

What it is doing now is inserting default_code text but not the values of the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a string instead of the field, try this:

```
self.squarebox = self.product_id.default_code
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use this:

```py
self.squarebox = self.product_id.default_code
```

when you do this :

```
self.squarebox = 'default_code'
```

it's like : `self.squarebox = 'string not a value of the field'`